# Why does "Compare with Latest Version" take so long to load the Diff tool on my machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Recently I've started seeing a 5-10 second delay between me clicking "Compare with Latest Version" on a file in the Pending Changes window, and the comparison tool coming up. In the interim, the status bar shows the message

> Running a compare operation in the background. Once the operation has completed, the results will be displayed in the compare tool.

I can't pinpoint when exactly this problem started, but none of my colleagues who're running the same setup are having this problem.

Any advice would be highly appreciated - those few seconds are long enough to throw my rhythm off.

Comment: Since VS2013 latest update seconds became minutes here. :(

Comment: Do you have DevExpress deployment tool installed?